# How can I find the dividend if I know the divisor and the remainder?

Tags: divisibility

A is a natural number. When it's divided by 12 the remainder is 9 and when it's divided by 16 the remainder is 13. What is the least possible value of A?

Comment: Division-algebras does not apply here at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

So,  the number $\displaystyle n\equiv9\pmod{12}-3\iff 12$ divides $n+3$

and $\displaystyle n\equiv13\pmod{16}\equiv-3\iff 16$ divides $n+3$

$\displaystyle\implies n\equiv-3\pmod{\text{lcm(12,16)}}$

or $n+3$ will divisible by lcm$(12,16)$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}A&=12k+9\\A&=16m+13\end{align*}\implies 4(4m-3k+1)=0\implies 4m-3k=-1\ldots$$

Comment: The number should be positive

Comment: @Ally, another way to look at it is $3k-4m=1$.  What are the smallest values of $k$ and $m$ that satisfy this?

Comment: Of course, @Ally: choose the minimal **positive**  $\;m,k\;$ that fulfill the rightmost equation and you'll get the minimal **positive** $\;A\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In the first case the number may be $9$, $21$, $33$ an so on.  What are the possible numbers in the second case? Write them down and find the smallest number that appears in both cases.